# PHP How to Group Multidimensional Array by associative Key Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this current PHP Array

```php
$newData = 

  array (size=3)
    0 => 
      array (size=6)
        'company_name' => string 'CO 1' (length=32)
        'year_and_filing_date' => string '2019' (length=4)
        'total_revenue' => string '200' (length=3)
        'net_income' => string '300' (length=3)
        'net_cash_ending_balance' => string '150' (length=3)
        'long-term_debt' => string '210' (length=3)
    1 => 
      array (size=6)
        'company_name' => string 'CO 1' (length=32)
        'year_and_filing_date' => string '2020' (length=4)
        'total_revenue' => string '200' (length=3)
        'net_income' => string '300' (length=3)
        'net_cash_ending_balance' => string '150' (length=3)
        'long-term_debt' => string '210' (length=3)
    2 => 
      array (size=6)
        'company_name' => string 'CO 1' (length=32)
        'year_and_filing_date' => string '2020' (length=4)
        'total_revenue' => string '100' (length=3)
        'net_income' => string '200' (length=3)
        'net_cash_ending_balance' => string '50' (length=2)
        'long-term_debt' => string '110' (length=3)
```

I want to merge all arrays with similar `'year_and_filling_date'` and sum all the
properties `'total_revenue'`, `'net_income'`, `'net_cash_ending_balance'` and `'long-term_debt'`

I am not sure where to start,

I am thinking of looping into each array to get unique
'year_and_filing_date'

```php
$unique_years = array_unique(
   array_map(function($elem){
      return $elem['year_and_filing_date'];
   },
   $newData)
);
```

result is `['2019','2020'];`

And then make another loop to filter the `$newData` with the result `['2019','2020']`

I am expecting to get two different arrays,
One returning 1 result and another one returning 2 result,

But how do i only sum selected fields?

Comment: *"But how do i only sum selected fields?"* What do you mean how? You just add them together. **Create new empty array**, **loop over your `$newData`-array** and **check if the index of the value in `year_and_filing_date` in your new array exists, if it does not just copy the selected values, otherwise add them up**. Additionally: How do you recieve this array? Via a database? Maybe you could use the group functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to filter, you can check if record with this year exists in foreach loop

```
$result = [];
foreach ($newData as $row) {
    $year = $row['year_and_filing_date'];
    if(!isset($result[$year])) {
        $result[$year]['total_revenue'] = $row['total_revenue'];
        $result[$year]['net_income'] = $row['net_income'];
        $result[$year]['net_cash_ending_balance'] = $row['net_cash_ending_balance'];
        $result[$year]['long-term_debt'] = $row['long-term_debt'];
        $result[$year]['last_scraped'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    } else {
        $result[$year]['total_revenue'] += $row['total_revenue'];
        $result[$year]['net_income'] += $row['net_income'];
        $result[$year]['net_cash_ending_balance'] += $row['net_cash_ending_balance'];
        $result[$year]['long-term_debt'] += $row['long-term_debt'];
        $result[$year]['last_scraped'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did so far,
it is working, but it is not optimized,
I hope someone can improve my code,

```
$newData = [];

/* Transform the Filling Date to Year */
array_walk($data, 
    function ($item2, $key) use (&$newData)
    {
        foreach($item2 as $keyAssoc => $val)
        {
            if($keyAssoc == 'year_and_filing_date')
            {
                if(!empty($val))
                {
                    $newData[$key][$keyAssoc] = date("Y", strtotime(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($val))));
                }
            }else{
                $newData[$key][$keyAssoc] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
);

/* Group Data by Years and Sum Up */
if(count($newData)>0)
{
    /* Get Unique Years */
    $unique_years = array_unique(array_map(function($elem){return $elem['year_and_filing_date'];}, $newData));
    asort($unique_years);

    $consolidatedData = [];
    foreach($unique_years as $key => $val)
    {
        foreach($newData as $k => $propertyName)
        {
            /* Compare if Year is Matching */
            if($propertyName['year_and_filing_date'] == $val)
            {
                
                $filteredData = array_filter($consolidatedData, function ($item) use ($val){
                    return $item['year_and_filing_date'] === $val;
                });

                /* Already Exists */
                if(count($filteredData)>0)
                {
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['company_name'] = $propertyName['company_name'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['year_and_filing_date'] = $val;
                    $total_revenue_raw = $filteredData[$val]['total_revenue'] + $propertyName['total_revenue'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['total_revenue'] = (string) $total_revenue_raw;
                    $net_income_raw = $filteredData[$val]['net_income'] + $propertyName['net_income'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['net_income'] = (string) $net_income_raw;
                    $net_cash_ending_balance_raw = $filteredData[$val]['net_cash_ending_balance'] + $propertyName['net_cash_ending_balance'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['net_cash_ending_balance'] = (string) $net_cash_ending_balance_raw;
                    $long_debt_raw = $filteredData[$val]['long-term_debt'] + $propertyName['long-term_debt'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['long-term_debt'] = (string) $long_debt_raw;
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['source_url'] = $propertyName['source_url'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['last_scraped'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
                }else{
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['company_name'] = $propertyName['company_name'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['year_and_filing_date'] = $val;
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['total_revenue'] = $propertyName['total_revenue'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['net_income'] = $propertyName['net_income'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['net_cash_ending_balance'] =$propertyName['net_cash_ending_balance'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['long-term_debt'] = $propertyName['long-term_debt'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['source_url'] = $propertyName['source_url'];
                    $consolidatedData[$val]['last_scraped'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return var_dump($consolidatedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of the solution from alibek.gao.

Input:

```
$newData = [
       ['company_name' => 'CO 1' , 'year_and_filing_date' => '2019', 'total_revenue' => '200',
        'net_income' => '300' , 'net_cash_ending_balance' => '150' ,  'long-term_debt' =>  '210'
       ],
       ['company_name' => 'CO 1', 'year_and_filing_date' => '2020', 'total_revenue' => '200',
        'net_income' => '300','net_cash_ending_balance' => '150',   'long-term_debt' => '210'
       ],
        ['company_name' => 'CO 1', 'year_and_filing_date' =>'2020',  'total_revenue' => '100',
        'net_income' => '200', 'net_cash_ending_balance' => '50',   'long-term_debt' => '110',
        ]
];
```

The algorithm can easily be written as a function.

```
$aggregateSum = ['total_revenue','net_income','net_cash_ending_balance','long-term_debt'];

$groupBy = 'year_and_filing_date';

$result = [];
foreach ($newData as $row) {
    $year = $row[$groupBy];
    if(!isset($result[$year])) {
        $result[$year] = $row;
    } else {
        foreach($aggregateSum as $field){
          $result[$year][$field] += $row[$field];
        }
    }
}
```

The non-totaled fields are retained with this solution:

The result:

```
array (
  2019 => 
  array (
    'company_name' => "CO 1",
    'year_and_filing_date' => "2019",
    'total_revenue' => "200",
    'net_income' => "300",
    'net_cash_ending_balance' => "150",
    'long-term_debt' => "210",
  ),
  2020 => 
  array (
    'company_name' => "CO 1",
    'year_and_filing_date' => "2020",
    'total_revenue' => 300,
    'net_income' => 500,
    'net_cash_ending_balance' => 200,
    'long-term_debt' => 320,
  ),
)
```